# Write unmanaged byte array to memory mapped file

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Is there a way to transfer unmanaged memory into a memory mapped file without needing to Marshal the unmanaged memory first?

I'm using an API which supplies me with ripped PDF data via a delegate. I get an IntPtr pointing to the data which I then use to marshal the unmanaged byte array to a managed byte array. I then write that array to a memory mapped file. I'm doing no processing on the byte array. All I do is write the array to a memory mapped file, then at a later point in time, I read the data back from the file and send it across the wire to another application (which is not a .Net application).

Is there a way I can do this without Marshaling? Is there a way that I could write the unmanaged data directly into a memory mapped file?

```
private void Callback( IntPtr data, int length )
{
    var buffer = new byte[ length ];
    Marshal.Copy( data, buffer, 0, length );
    _memoryMappedViewStream.Write( buffer, 0, length );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, this comes down to: is there an API that lets you pass *in* a pointer for the PDF code to write to. If so, you can presumably get hold of the unmanaged pointer for the memory mapped file via a view-accessor (`CreateViewAccessor`) and `.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer()` - hand that pointer to the *other* API to write to directly, without you ever having to get in the middle. Remember to call `ReleasePointer()` when you've finished with it.

If that doesn't exist, then you'll need to copy the data once, which is what you're doing. I might be tempted to use `Unsafe.CopyBlock` (from `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`) rather than `Marshal.Copy`, but I expect that they're doing the same thing.

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured that would be the case. Thanks Marc.